Power BI report refresh get same filtered data
When I refresh a Power BI report before refresh which filtered I added I want same filtered after refresh page
const embedReport = useCallback(
    async (embedUrl: string, embedToken: string) => {
      const config: powerbi.IEmbedConfiguration = {
        type: 'report',
        id: activeReport?.reportId,
        embedUrl: embedUrl,
        accessToken: embedToken,
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
        settings: {
          panes: {
            filters: {
              visible: false
            },
            pageNavigation: {
              visible: false
            }
          }
        }
      };

      if (embedContainer.current) {
        window.powerbi?.preload({
          type: 'report',
          embedUrl: embedUrl
        });
        window.powerbi?.bootstrap(embedContainer.current, config);

        const embeddedReport = window.powerbi?.embed(embedContainer.current, config) as powerbi.Report;
        let startTime = performance.now();
        embeddedReport.on('loaded', async function (e) {
          let endTime = performance.now();
          appInsightCustomEvent.trackEvent({
            name: 'PowerBi Load Time',
            properties: {
              loadTime: endTime - startTime,
              measurementType: 'ms',
              reportId: activeReport?.reportId,
              reportName: activeReport?.displayName
            }
          });
          const reportOffSetWidth = document.getElementById('powerbi-report-container')?.offsetWidth;
          embeddedReport?.getPages().then((pages) => {
            if (pages && pages.length > 0) {
              const activePage = pages?.find((ele) => ele.isActive);
              const activePageHeight = activePage?.defaultSize.height;
              const activePageWidth = activePage?.defaultSize.width;
              appInsightCustomEvent?.trackPageView({
                name: `powerBi report page viewed`,
                properties: {
                  pageName: activePage?.displayName,
                  reportName: activeReport?.displayName,
                  reportId: activeReport?.reportId
                }
              });
              let reportHeight: string | number = 0;
              if (activePageHeight && activePageWidth) {
                const r = activePageWidth / activePageHeight;
                reportHeight = Number(reportOffSetWidth) / r;
                // Set the height of the container to match the report height
                if (embedContainer.current) {
                  embedContainer.current.style.height = reportHeight + 'px';
                }
              }

              // Adjust the height dynamically if the content changes
              embeddedReport.on('pageChanged', (event) => {
                const selectedPageName = (event.detail as { newPage: { displayName: string } }).newPage;
                const selectedPage = pages?.find((ele) => ele.displayName == selectedPageName.displayName);
                const selectedPageHeight = selectedPage?.defaultSize.height;

                appInsightCustomEvent?.trackPageView({
                  name: `powerBi report page viewed`,
                  properties: {
                    pageName: selectedPage?.displayName,
                    reportName: activeReport?.displayName,
                    reportId: activeReport?.reportId
                  }
                });
                if (selectedPageHeight && activePageWidth) {
                  const r = activePageWidth / selectedPageHeight;
                  reportHeight = Number(reportOffSetWidth) / r;
                  if (embedContainer.current) {
                    // Set the height of the container to match the report height
                    embedContainer.current.style.height = reportHeight + 'px';
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
          embeddedReport.iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
          setPowerBiReport(embeddedReport);
        });
        let renderTimeStart = performance.now();
        embeddedReport.on('rendered', async () => {
          let renderTimeEnd = performance.now();
          appInsightCustomEvent.trackEvent({
            name: 'PowerBi render time',
            properties: {
              renderTime: renderTimeEnd - renderTimeStart,
              measurementType: 'ms',
              reportId: activeReport?.reportId,
              reportName: activeReport?.displayName
            }
          });
          const currentZoom = await embeddedReport?.getZoom();
          console.log(` ~ setDefaultZoom: ${currentZoom}`);
          logger.log(` ~ setDefaultZoom: ${currentZoom}`);
          setDefaultZoom(currentZoom);

          try {
            const accessToken = await PowerBiService.getAccessToken();

            if (!accessToken) {
              throw new Error('powerbi-access-token-err');
            }
          } catch (error: any) {
            setErrMessage(error.message);
          }
          embeddedReport.on('error', (event) => {
            const error = event.detail as { message: string };
            if (error.message === 'TokenExpired') {
              setErrMessage('powerbi-access-token-err');
            }
            setErrMessage(error.message);
          });
        });
      }
    },
    [activeReport?.reportId, embedContainer]
  );

This what I have implemented, but I am stuck.

Your first sentence is grammatically incorrect, making it difficult to understand what your question or problem is. Please edit the question to explain more clearly what you are trying to accomplish and where you are stuck.
